# Add page break in table in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to force a page break in a Google Docs table?

I've got a table that is going to extend across multiple pages and I'd like to choose where the break happens (I want to keep a row together). Is this possible?

The Insert > Page Break menu item is grayed out when I am in the table. Another option would be to break the table into sections, but I'm not seeing a nice way to do that either (nothing akin to the Table > Split Table menu item in Microsoft Word).

Comment: Click View > Print Layout......(Courtsey **Chris Hick** [here] (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/NoSbHLD_bnk))

Answer (score 17):

To split a table in Google Docs:

1. Select the bottom part of the table - everything below the point where you want the split.
2. Drag it below the table
3. Delete the empty rows that are left behind

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is an addon I published for this.
From addons menu of Google Doc > get addons
Search for 'Doc Table'.

Once you add this to your docs addon menu, you can either split a row in to next page or line.

This will work only for table contents inside Google Docs.

Comment: Thanks for the addon, but this basically splits the table and adds a page break. nice to have a macro that does that, but it's different than a "page break in a table", because with your solution the result are 2 separate tables. For example: changing columns of one will not affect the other. I appreciate that this is the best we've got a this point, but not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @user141542 I'm trying install your Add-on and I get an error from Google saying "This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In." Is there anything you can do to fix it? Thanks!